# drawInRect withAttributes Crashing on iOS8 GM

Tags: ios8, drawrect, uigraphicscontext

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
CGContextRef    ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIFont *bigFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:bigFontSize-2];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyleCenter = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyleCenter.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyleCenter.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSDictionary *bigCenter = @{ NSFontAttributeName: bigFont,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyleCenter };
CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kMarginInset, kMarginInset -15, (pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset), stringSize.height);


[tempS drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes:bigCenter]; //Crash //tempS & renderingRect are valid
```

This is only crashing when I generate a PDF using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile,

I use the same code for a UIView and it works fine.

This worked fine for iOS7

Comment: So drawInRect throws a exception that isn't fatal, disabling all exceptions breakpoint fixed it

Comment: Confirmed. Same issue generating a pdf file. Non fatal. Must be a bug.

Comment: Still present on 8.1. 

Incidentally- the problem goes away if I set NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle, but that does not make sense as a requirement.